# Facebook PHP SDK works only on localhost

Tags: php, facebook, cakephp-1.2

I have a mobile app which was interfacing with the PHP Facebook SDK fine until recently. Now it will only sign in when I have it pointed at my localhost development server. Frankly, I'm completely stumped. Of course I've checked the site url inside the Facebook developer center. Everything is pointed at the live server. Yet only the development server will sign in. Any suggestions?

```
These domains work:
http://localhost:8888
http://testsite2:8888

These domains will not work:
http://*.com
https://*.com
```

As requested, here is my facebook code:

```
$config = array();
$config['appId'] = Configure::read('FB_APP_ID');
$config['secret'] = Configure::read('FB_APP_SECRET');
$config['fileUpload'] = false; // optional
$facebook = new Facebook($config);      
$facebook->setAccessToken($this->data['User']['fbtoken']);
$receivedfbid = $facebook->getUser();
```

This works correctly on my development server and it used to work fine on the live server until recently. Just to reiterate, the facebook developer center is configured for "site url" to the live server. So that is not the problem.

[image]

Comment: show your facebook code

Comment: Do you have an [SSL certificate](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/497/) at your live server?

Comment: yes I do have an ssl cert on the live server. Are you referring to the ssl cert for the server? Or the facebook ssl key that resides in the facebook directory? I have both, but also I've tested on non-ssl connections as well and it doesn't work.

Comment: could you post a screenshot of your app settings.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my web app on webhost but it worked fine on localhost.

In my case it was related to cURL and ssl.

A quick way to see if it is a SSL problem is to tell fb php sdk to accept any SSL cert, to do that, Add this to your base_facebook.php file:

```
$opts[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER] = false; 
   curl_setopt_array($ch, $opts);
```

Place it right before `$result = curl_exec($ch);`

I know you said you tested on non SSL connections but your base_facebook.php file is still looking for a ssl cert.
For further reading see: http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/

Answer (score -1):

Change your app setting  in [developer.facebook.com](http://developer.facebook.com) I hope you would configured for localhost

Comment: As I already stated. I've checked the site url settings inside Facebook developer center. They are pointed at the correct url